# how to show jQuery Model dialog box through Asp.Net ajax UpdateProgress

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can i show  the jQuery 
 *model dialogBox*  in the *ProgressTemplate* of  UpdateProgress (Asp.net Ajax)
I have downloaded the latest jquery. Have included it in file. 
I want to know what else need to be done.
I want a fade effect  in the entire screen with the dialog showing an animated .gif image.
Can any one guide in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u look some thing like this.
http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx

Comment: "The page you're looking for is not available..." - That's why answers that just link offsite suck for people like me, looking to find the answer 5 years later.